# Group by + all in ...?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know if all joined values are in another table.

Example:

```
id childId
1  2
1  3
1  4
2  6
2  7
2  8
2  9

childIds
2
3
4
6
7



 **desired result:**

id allChildrenInChildIds
1  True
2  False
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05b65/1)**

```
select id, case when sum(TrueorFalse) = count(1) then 'true'
                else 'false' end
from (
select id, case  when exists (select 1 from ChildIDs where id = childid) then 1
             else 0 
             end as TrueOrFalse
from child ) A
group by A.id
```

Using When Exists (select ... from ...)

Comment: this one seemed to be the easiest to understand and produced the desired result... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you run this query

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(childId) 
FROM  table 
WHERE childId NOT IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,8) 
GROUP BY id
```

any ideas in the result will be false.  I added the GROUP_CONCAT so you could determine which childId's were not in the set.  If an id isn't in the results then it is true.

Comment: the NOT IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,8)  Could also be NOT IN (SELECT id FROM childIds)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    ID
   ,MIN(allChildrenInChildIds) 
FROM 
(
   SELECT id,
   CASE WHEN childId  IN (SELECT childIds FROM Table2) THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE'
   END AS allChildrenInChildIds
   FROM Table1
) result 
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
select
  id,
  case when exists (
    select c.childid
    from Child as c
    where c.id = ids.id
    and not exists (
      select *
      from Childids
      where c.childid = Childids.id
    )) then 'No' else 'Yes' end as WereAllChildrenFound
from ids
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

```
select id , case when count(c.childid) <> count(ci.childid) then 'false' else 'true' end as allChildrenInChildIds
from Child c 
left join ChildIds ci 
on c.childid = ci.childid 
group by id
```